# Control html dynamically without component re rendering in React with Apollo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo-client

In my current situation, I use Apollo `useQuery` to fetch a user and their posts.

The posts render in a summary view and in a detailed view. the detailed view is sitting on top of the summary view and its visibility is controlled by a piece of state.

```
  const { data: userData, error: userError } = useQuery(GET_USER_BY_ID, { // the data fetch
    variables: {
      userId: getUserId(),
    }
  })


  const [showPosts, setShowPosts] = useState(false) // controls toggle between views
```

the problem im having is every time the `showPosts` state changes the component re renders and the `useQuery` is run again. which I do not want. I have already got all my data, I just want to render html without hitting the server again until I need to. What is a potential solution to my problem?

Comment: Why aren't you fetching data in useEffect hook? You can also provide a dependency array

Answer (score 0):

Check [skip](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#skip) param, You can do something like this:

```
const { data: userData, error: userError } = useQuery(GET_USER_BY_ID, { // the data fetch
        variables: {
          userId: getUserId(),
          skip:!showPosts
        }
      })
```

or use [useLazyQuery](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#uselazyquery)